# I want to join 2 of this result

Tags: sql

I want to query the actor whos play both movie RANDOM GO and JASON TRAP

but it look like i can't just use AND in my SQL Statement

Please Advise Me.

```
SELECT A.first_name, A.last_name, F.title FROM actor AS A
    JOIN film_actor AS Fa ON A.actor_id = Fa.actor_id
    JOIN film AS F ON F.film_id = Fa.film_id 
WHERE F.title = 'RANDOM GO' AND F.title ='JASON TRAP'
ORDER BY A.first_name;
```

```
SELECT A.first_name, A.last_name, F.title FROM actor AS A
    JOIN film_actor AS Fa ON A.actor_id = Fa.actor_id
    JOIN film AS F ON F.film_id = Fa.film_id 
WHERE F.title = 'RANDOM GO' 
ORDER BY A.first_name;
```

```
SELECT A.first_name, A.last_name, F.title FROM actor AS A
    JOIN film_actor AS Fa ON A.actor_id = Fa.actor_id
    JOIN film AS F ON F.film_id = Fa.film_id 
WHERE F.title = 'JASON TRAP' 
ORDER BY A.first_name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if it solve your problem:

```
SELECT A.first_name, A.last_name
FROM actor AS A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM film_actor AS Fa
                   JOIN film AS F ON F.film_id = Fa.film_id
              WHERE A.actor_id = Fa.actor_id AND F.title = 'RANDOM GO') --
      AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM film_actor AS Fa
                       JOIN film AS F ON F.film_id = Fa.film_id
                  WHERE A.actor_id = Fa.actor_id AND F.title = 'JASON TRAP')
ORDER BY A.first_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS for the second condition, but it would be better to have a unique identifier for the actrs, as there could be more than one actor in two movies with the same name

```
SELECT A.first_name, A.last_name, F.title FROM actor AS A
    JOIN film_actor AS Fa ON A.actor_id = Fa.actor_id
    JOIN film AS F ON F.film_id = Fa.film_id 
WHERE F.title = 'RANDOM GO' AND EXISTS
(
SELECT A.first_name, A.last_name, F.title FROM actor AS A1
    JOIN film_actor AS Fa ON A1.actor_id = Fa.actor_id
    JOIN film AS F ON F.film_id = Fa.film_id 
WHERE F.title = 'JASON TRA AND A.first_name 
= A1.first_name AND  A.last_name  A1.last_name)
ORDER BY A.first_name;
```